# How to set a TCP service backend?

Tags: docker, traefik

I have a MQTT broker started via `docker-compose` and managed by `traefik`:

```
  mqtt:
    container_name: mqtt
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    restart: always
    labels:
      - 'traefik.port=1883'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mqtt2.ex.com'
      - 'traefik.frontend.entryPoints=mqtt'
    ports:
      - 3883:1883
```

The relevant part of `traefik.toml` where I am trying to set up the backend:

```
[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.mqtt]
address = ":2884"

[tcp] # YAY!
   [tcp.routers]
      [tcp.routers.mqtt]
         entrypoints = ["mqtt"]
         rule = "HostSNI(`*`)" # Catches every request       
         service = "mqtt"
   [tcp.services]
   [tcp.services.mqtt.LoadBalancer]


I can access the broker via port `3883` but this is not what I intend to do (the exposed port above is just to make sure that the container is OK): I would like to proxy it though `traefik` like all my other **HTTP** services.

This however is not a HTTP service, it is a TCP one and my problem is that **I do not know how to configure such a TCP backend**.
```

The [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/routing/services/) is very light on that feature, it just states that

> Currently, `LoadBalancer` is the only supported kind of TCP Service.
>   However, since Traefik is an ever evolving project, other kind of TCP
>   Services will be available in the future, reason why you have to
>   specify it.

What does this means in terms of configuring the backend? What should I add to either `docker-compose.yaml` or `traefik.toml` so that the backend is recognized as a TCP service? For the moment, it is seen as a HTTP one and the proxification does not work:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. I really thought http is tcp... In docker-compose you can specify the protocol tcp or udp but the default is tcp so is what you have. I do think that your service is available on 2884 and routed through traefik. Is that not so? If not could you explain better what exactly you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: @Mihai: `traefik` used to proxify the HTTP protocol only (which yes, is on top of TCP and IP, networking speaking). They recently added the possibility to proxify any kind of raw TCP traffic but the documentation on how to set up the backend for that is non-existent. If you look at my screenshot, you will see that the backend expects HTTP.